# Input doesn't work when used with debounce, event.persist() and storing value at parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I need an input field with debounced search and value should be passed from parent component. But it doesn't work when value passed from parent component. What is the right way to implement it?

Codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/debounce-input-owdwj

Text field with debouncing

```
class MyTextField extends Component {
  search = _.debounce(event => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
  }, 300);

  handleChangeInput = event => {
    event.persist();

    this.search(event);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder="type"
        onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component storing the value of text field

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleChangeInput = value => {
    this.setState({
      value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.value}</h2>
        <MyTextField
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think responsibilities of components are not quite clear here. I would use the following architecture: have a textfield with a build-in debounce feature. It should have a state with the actual textfield's value but passing the changes upwards debounced. Its parent (MyTextField) should handle the async operation, and no need to pass down any field value to textfield. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are updating the component only after 300 seconds which will not update the input box also. first, you need to update the search box component whenever there is a keyup and later parent can be informed about the changed after 300 seconds
I have updated your code reference please check it out https://codesandbox.io/embed/debounce-input-gm50t

Answer (score 1):

Declare your debounce function in componentDidMount is everything will be fine.

1) Without state

```
class MyTextField extends Component {
  handleChangeInput = e => {
    this.search(e.target.value)
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.search =_.debounce((value) => {
      this.props.onChange(value);
    }, 300)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder="type"
        onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyTextField;
```

2) With state:

```
class MyTextField extends Component {
  state = {
    textValue: ''
  }

  handleChangeInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      textValue: e.target.value
    }, () => { this.search()})
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.search =_.debounce(() => {
      this.props.onChange(this.state.textValue);
    }, 300)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder="type"
        onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyTextField;
```

Hope that helps!!!